# Sending data using socket to a specified running thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

I have a multithreading socket server that create a seperate thread for every connected client to do some data processing. Actually, I can receive data from all the connected clients and doing the same data processing for every one.

What I need to do now is to send some data to a specified connected client without blocking communication ( I need full duplex communication). My questions are :

1) How can I identifie the thread holding the wanted client ?
2) Is it possible to send some data to this client without blocking the communication ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible by using separate threads for reading from (and processing) and sending to each client. The threads can share a BlockingQueue such as ArrayBlockingQueue, the processing thread would write to it, and the sending thread would read from it and send to the client.

Actually, another way is to separate the reading thread from the processing thread, and have the processing thread do the sending too. You can use Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor for processing, and have the reading thread send "jobs" to it via the execute method.

You can also use a networking library such as Apache MINA, which implements all the details for you, and also uses async sockets with a customizable thread model for greater scalability.

Comment: This is not really Helpfull. I don't want to block communication betwwen client and server at any time. My threads are created dynamicly using the Runnable interface.

Comment: Where exactly do you think my solution was blocking the communication? Anyway I also added another approach now. I guess it's possible to combine them too.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the communication using `SocketChannel`. It supports full-duplex with non-blocking communication.

See [SocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) for more information about it.

As channels are fairly different to streams, here is a short [Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/socket-channel.html) on SocketChannels with a small example to start from.

Comment: This is a good solution if I control both the server side and the client side which is not the case. I only can handle the server side. Is that possible ?

Comment: @abdelbari-anouar Currently I'm not sure, what you really can influence in your program. If the client is fixed, it expects a certain protocol (or way of communication, if you wish). Communication must happen in exactly the way the client expects it and with the channels the client has implemented. What client are you working with? What does this client expects in terms of channels (socket streams, socket channels, TCP, Datagram) and sequence of communication?

Comment: That's it ! you are right. In fact I'm dealing with a GPS Traker which send his data to a specific server that I'm implementing. I need to deal with with all connected trackers and send to it some command from time to time for this reason I can't control the client side. Thanks @jboi !